# File name too long in Azure Web App Service CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to pull my changes from the git repository but I got the error **Filename too long**.

To resolve this issue, I tried running the command `git config --system core.longpaths true` but I get `Permission denied error: could not lock config file` error. I think this is normal because running the command above requires admin CLI.

Would like to ask if there's any way I can enable the longpaths in azure web app service?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: I wasn't able to fix the issue. The workaround we did was to exclude the affected files on the git repository.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use below command.

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

Comment: I tried this command but I still get the error.

Comment: Try ,`git config core.longpaths true`.

Comment: Tried and I get this 

`D:\home\site\wwwroot>git config core.longpaths true
fatal: not in a git directory`